# Vue-Test-Utils Unknown custom element: <router-link>

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, jestjs, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I'm using Jest to run my tests utilizing the vue-test-utils library.

Even though I've added the VueRouter to the localVue instance, it says it can't actually find the router-link component. If the code looks a little funky, it's because I'm using TypeScript, but it should read pretty close to ES6... Main thing is that the @Prop() is the same as passing in props: {..}

**Vue component:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="temp">
      <div>
        <router-link :to="temp.url">{{temp.name}}</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { Temp } from './Temp'

@Component({
  name: 'temp'
})
export default class TempComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop() private temp: Temp
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.temp {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

**Temp model:**

```js
export class Temp {
  public static Default: Temp = new Temp(-1, '')

  public url: string

  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {
    this.id = id
    this.name = name
    this.url = '/temp/' + id
  }
}
```

**Jest test**

```js
import { createLocalVue, shallow } from '@vue/test-utils'
import TempComponent from '@/components/Temp.vue'
import { Temp } from '@/components/Temp'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)

describe('Temp.vue Component', () => {
  test('renders a router-link tag with to temp.url', () => {
    const temp = Temp.Default
    temp.url = 'http://some-url.com'

    const wrapper = shallow(TempComponent, {
      propsData: { temp }
    })
    const aWrapper = wrapper.find('router-link')
    expect((aWrapper.attributes() as any).to).toBe(temp.url)
  })
})
```

What am I missing? The test actually passes, it just throws the warning. In fact, here is the output:

**Test Output:**

```
$ jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js
 PASS  ClientApp\components\__tests__\temp.spec.ts
  Temp.vue Component
    √ renders a router-link tag with to temp.url (30ms)

  console.error node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js:589
    [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the 
component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the 
"name" option.

    (found in <Root>)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.677s
Ran all test suites.
Done in 6.94s.
```

Appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: you need to register router-link as a stub.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Add the `router-link` stub to the `shallow` (or `shallowMount`) method options like this:

```js
const wrapper = shallow(TempComponent, {
     propsData: { temp },
     stubs: ['router-link']
})
```

or [this way](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/components/#routerlinkstub):

```js
import { RouterLinkStub } from '@vue/test-utils';

const wrapper = shallow(TempComponent, {
     propsData: { temp },
     stubs: {
         RouterLink: RouterLinkStub
     }
})
```

The error should go away after you do this.

Comment: Second way worked for me. The `html()` function returned `<!---->` wherever I was using `<router-link...`. After using a `localVue` and `RouterLinkStub`, it rendered my `<router-link...` properly to the `<a...` so that I could test the existence and values for data inside the `<router-link`.

The OP was trying to use `wrapper.find('router-link')` and I don't think this answer solves that problem. But it solved mine, which was a similar one.

Comment: This is not working in version 1.0.0-beta.11. For what version is this solution?

Comment: Is there a way to make the test fail instead of outputting the warning message?

Comment: also can use 
**const wrapper = mount(Status, {
        stubs: ['router-link']
    })**

Answer (score 5):

With Vue 3 and Vue Test Utils Next (v4), it seems you just have to add your `router` (the return object from `createRouter`) as a plugin to your `mountOptions`:

```js
import router from "@/router";

const mountOptions = {
  global: {
    plugins: [router],
  },
};
```

https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global

Or a more full example:

```js
import router from "@/router";
import Button from "@/components/Button.vue";

const mountOptions = {
  global: {
    mocks: {
      $route: "home",
      $router: {
        push: jest.fn(),
      },
    },
    plugins: [router],
  },
};


it("Renders", () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Button, mountOptions);
  expect(wrapper.get("nav").getComponent({ name: "router-link" })).toExist();
});
```

Note, in the example above I'm using a project setup with Vue CLI.

Comment: accepted answer didn't work for me but this one did. Nice job!

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

[ Package.json ] file

```
...
"vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
"vue-router": "~3.1.5",
"vue": "~2.6.11",
"@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
...
```

[ Test ] file

```
import App from '../../src/App';
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'dashboard',
      path: '/dashboard'
    }
  ]
});

describe('Successful test', ()=>{
  it('works', ()=>{    
    let wrapper = mount(App, {
      localVue,
      router
    });

    // Here is your assertion
  });
});
```

Or you can try this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
const wrapper = shallow(TempComponent, {
  propsData: { temp },
  localVue
})
```